# How to set value to angular input

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi I am trying to set value to a angular input box but when i do

```js
let input = document.getElementById('mat-input-0');
input.value = "Something"
```

input box value changes on website but angular does not see any value when I try hit button and set form

Comment: Because this isn't Angular, this is JS. Before using a framework, take some time, and [RTFM](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview) !

Comment: That's not how you should approach things. Read the documentation. You'll want to use a model, and change the value of the model. https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Comment: It is not my project and I never used Angular before and I need to add some new features and I could not find answer to my question anywhere :(

Comment: The angular doc is a good place to start. If you need to work on a techno that you don't know it should be your first move.

Comment: Yes you are right I just didn't want to read docs because it was minor change so I thought I will handle It without docs

Comment: According to [ask], it is recommended to research before asking questions. If I'm not mistaken, you are trying to set the value of input. I recommend looking into the link @TimVN provided. [This guide](https://angular.io/guide/user-input) could possibly help you with user input.

Comment: I did a search but everything what I found did not answer my question, because I wanted to use Javascript to do that now I see that It probably won't be possible so I will read about angular and do It right way Instead of finding some "hack"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the input value property:

```
<input [value]="value">
```

or get the element in your TS file using `@ViewChild`:

html:

TS:

```
@ViewChild('input', { static: false }) input: ElementRef;

  AfterViewInit() {
    // Change the value here
  }
```